Minimum Bernoulli trials for sampling pairs of coin flips
I'm simplifying a research problem related to sampling from a time-correlated distribution. I have $n$ coins, labeled $c_1,c_2,...,c_n$. For each unique pair of coins, say ($c_i,c_j$), I assign a biased "hidden" coin flip $h_{ij}$. If this hidden coin lands on heads ($h_{ij}=1$), both coins in the pair will be heads ($c_i=c_j=1$); if tails ($h_{ij}=0$), both will be tails ($c_i=c_j=0$). Therefore, there are ${n\choose{2}}=\frac{n(n-1)}2$ hidden coins.
For each individual coin $c_k$, I determine its outcome by taking the sum (mod 2) of the hidden coin flips for each pair involving $c_k$. Specifically:
$$
c_k=\sum_{h_{ij}:i=k~\text{or}~j=k}h_{ij}~\text{mod}~2.
$$

Is ${n\choose{2}}$ the minimum number of bernoulli trials to exactly sample from this distribution?
What are good approximate sampling methods that could be applied in this situation?


This sampling method does not make sense to me.  What if $h_{12}=1$ and $h_{23}=0$ --- is the second coin a head or tail?  (But then later you give the mod equation, which is inconsistent with what you first said about the outcome of the coins.)
